# Deducing finiteness of the integrand from finiteness of integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, analysis, hilbert-spaces, inner-products

Suppose we know that:
$$
\int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} \, g(k) \,  h^2(k) \, dk  \leq\int_{ [-\pi, \pi]^d} \, h(k) \, dk < \infty.
$$
where $h(k) = \sin(\frac{k_1}{2})^2 +  \sum_{i=2}^{d} \sin(k_i)^2.$
Assuming $d > 2$, is it possible from this to deduce that,
$$
\int_{[-\pi, \pi]^d} \, g(k)  < \infty? 
$$

Comment: where is the singularity in $h$?

Comment: Sorry, I made a small mistake. I corrected it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your question is: no, at least for $d<5$.

Consider $g(x)=\frac{\int_{ [-\pi, \pi]^d} \, h(k) \, dk}{h^2(x)}$. Then clearly the desired conditions are satisfied. However, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^d$ such that $x\simeq 0$ one has
$$
h(x)\simeq |x|^2,
$$
since
$$
\sin y\simeq y, \quad \textrm{for}\quad y\sim 0,\, y\in\mathbb{R}.
$$
Consequently,
$$
g(x)\simeq |x|^{-4}, \quad \textrm{for}\quad x\sim 0,
$$
thus $g$ is not integrable for $d<5$.

Comment: Thank you! Do you think it can be true in general for $d \geq 5$?

Comment: No problem. Yes, one can construct a similar counterexample for any $d$. Note that we can always rescale by the integral of $h$, as in my solution, so the problem boils down to constructing $g$ such that $\int g h^2<\infty$ and $\int g=\infty$. Taking $g(x)=|x|^{-d-1}$ does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Not in general. Take the case $d=1$ and $g(k) = 1/h(k) =1/\sin^2(k)$.